# VBA obtaining Dropbox file path for multiple users (Mac and PC)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, dropbox

I created an excel file housed within a specific Dropbox folder that uses a macro to append a date and time stamp to certain tabs of the file and then saves it to that same folder.

On a PC, the path is something like

`C:\Users\MyName\Dropbox\Daily History\`

while on a MAC it is something like

`Macintosh HD: Users: meadowbrook: Documents:`

The only thing I can think of to make it dynamic is somehow using CELL("filename") and dynamically storing it as a variable.  Is there a way to just save as to the directory the file is in without needing to specify the path in VBA?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Macintosh HD: Users: meadowbrook: Documents:" & Name2 is the what it looks like on a MAC and     ChDir "C:\Users\MyName\Dropbox\Daily History"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\MyName\Dropbox\Daily History\Name 2 is the PC version.  Name2 is the time / date variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

for just the path itself (without the workbook name) or

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

for the path with the workbook name

Comment: What is happening is that I have a macro enabled workbook, and the macro cuts three tabs out and appends a date / time stamp to the new file in xlsx and needs to save this file in the same Dropbox folder. Are you saying an ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs would suffice where a specific path would not need to be specified?

Comment: See my edit.  I think you need Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & Name2, or something along those lines.

Comment: You might have to tinker with it a bit, but it should be close to that.  I'd put a code break in just before that statement and see what it thinks Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path is equal to (either by hovering your mouse over it or using Debug.Print, or even by setting a messagebox up to display it), and then adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: It works without the "/".  The one issue I have is that I have a workbooks.add function right before this syntax (which defaults to My Documents).  Is there a way to use the  Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path to enable the workbooks.add to be created at a specific location? Otherwise the final result saves to My Documents.

Comment: Try ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\new workbook.xls" just after your ActiveWorkbooks.Add statement.  If this helps, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer so future users can know it worked.